# Proposal: Hunting Tag

Tags: discussion, status-declined

Question is simple. How do we feel about a hunting tag here, or just hunting questions in general? Hunting is certainly a sport, but is there a better place to post any questions relating to it?

Personally I think adding a hunting tag here is a good idea unless there is somewhere else already.

Comment: Seems like hunting should go on [outdoors.SE]

Comment: @waxeagle Interesting. I didn't even know that site existed, but that makes sense. In fact, they seem to have a hunting tag already...

Comment: @Mansfield I agree with wax eagle. There are competitive outdoor sports (competitive bass fishing, for example) that may be on-topic...but until a question like such is asked, it is hard to tell if it belongs here or The Great Outdoors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an answer instead of comments:

1. Adding tags should only be done when asking a question that merits the tag. Adding tags isn't supported outside of this (in fact if a tag doesn't have at least 2 questions it will disappear after a certain amount of time).
2. TGO already covers hunting and it's not *played as a competitive sport* for the most part. Questions about hunting competitions (how they are formatted etc) would probably be welcome both here and at TGO (although you're likely to find people with the right expertise there rather than here).

If we do get hunting question then we can evaluate them on their merits and topicality (and maybe revisit this then), but for now TGO seems like a good place to start for people with hunting questions.